# Freeze push heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to do a deploy on heroku and freezes on the last step,**Fetching http://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git**

```
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching http://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the gem as a plugin (only if Rails version less than 4.0):

```
$ rails plugin install git://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git
```

prototype_legacy helper is no longer maintained.